# Feeds UI Design

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I am building a website which requires the feeds facility (like what you have in Facebook or Google Plus).

Facebook uses single column feeds, Google uses multi column feeds which are card based.

**My Question:**

Which layout is best suited for a good UI where the user gets enough attention to most of the feed contents as well as feels easy to work with? I am ready to use any layout apart from what Google or FB uses. So, is there any other better way to represent feeds?

Of course for handheld devices, the transition will happen to single column feeds due to the limited screen space. But what about other devices.

PS: I am not only concerned about the columns for the feeds but also better way to represent them.

I did refer: [1-column vs n-column timelines / news feeds](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/43891/1-column-vs-n-column-timelines-news-feeds)

**UPDATE:**

The website I am developing is a social networking website. So, the content which will be displayed in the feed will include user posts, images, videos, etc. (Any User generated content)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you describe the content you want to display in that feed ?

Comment: So, is the question: what's the best design for a social network?

Comment: Just use Google's one and you won't make a mistake. Google is the world leader in usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a facebook based scroll but keep in mind that Infinite scrolling can decline your bounce rate. Time.com’s bounce rate down 15 percentage points since adopting continuous scroll...you can read about it here: https://blog.growth.supply/13-mind-blowing-statistics-on-user-experience-48c1e1ede755

I think if you are going to adopt any feed, facebook feed is widely recognized and more users are used to it as oppose to google +

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I went through the link you referred and I am convinced about all the facts it says but I am still not sure if there is any better way to represent a feed than what Facebook does. Sure, its good but what if there is some better way?

Comment: I am sure there is....the dilemma you might be facing then....1.retention? 2. re inventing user habits....most people are used to and are familiar with FB scroll....and for the most part feel comfortable with it, why take time and possible loss of visitors by re inventing the wheel? if it works cool...if you want to be a visionary then i respect that and hope you do find something more useful but remember that it will come with a price of possibly losing few visitors who might be confused by the structure.

Comment: Yup. I do understand your point. Thanks a lot. I will wait a bit more to see if there are any other answers, else, I will go with yours :-)

Comment: haha no problem. good luck to you :)

Answer (score 0):

As a frequent user of Google plus, I'd say: let the user decide. Depending on screen size and window size one might like to use a three or more column layout and others prefer wide items in a single column. Just create a simple slider widget to let them choose for their own and set a sensible default like 2 columns.